# How to migrate data from one table to different tables using conditions in TALEND

Tags: data-migration, talend

I have a requirement where i need to migrate data from one table of oracle DB to different tables based on condition like if tableA contains value A in one column then insert it into tableA else insert it into tableB. Can we do this using TALEND.
Someone please guide me.

Comment: from tOracleInput-->tMap and in tMap you can create different output groups and apply group filters/conditions in these..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do conditional load in Talend. and based on your scenario you can use filter expression of Talend to do it. check screen for more details.

[image]

add two oracle output for loading into table A and table B like below screen.

[image]

Comment: which component do i need to use. Could you please deign the job diagram

Comment: added simple job design.

Comment: Thanks Umesh...it worked perfectly...only point i want to make over here is it should be 'equals' and not '=='..:)